# Control Objects in a usercontrol from another usercontrol

Tags: c#

In my Form (Form1) I have 2 Usercontrols (usercontrol1 & usercontrol1). On the first Usercontrol (usercontrol1) is a button (button1) and on the second one (usercontrol2) is a label (label1). I want to change the Text of the "label1" by clicking on the button "button1".
I have tryed so many things and looked in many forums but could solve the Problem.

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void changeText()
        {
            userControl21.label1.Text = "Test!";
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }
    }
```

Usercontrol1 Code

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl2 UC = new UserControl2();
            UC.label1.Text = "Text!";

            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.changeText();
        }
    }
```

Usercontrol2 Code

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

As seen in the Code of "Usercontrol1" i tried to change the text directly and then i tried to change it by running a method on "Form1" which sould change the Text.
Unfortunelly nothing worked and I couldnt find any working solution in many forums.
Does anyone know how to do that.

When I change the text of the label in "Form1" without the method which is started from "Usercontrol1" the text of the label changes without any problems.

Comment: Generally, the point of a UserControl is to encapsulate various functionality and *avoid* one thing messing about in another things sandbox.If you are to continue down this ill-advised path, use the *existing* ones by passing a reference to the object or fetching it rather than creating a `new` one which will create a *new* one

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Think of the Form as the mediator between your controls, you don't generally want your controls to know about each other. Instead you want your Form to orchestrate the actions and data between your controls.

**UserControl1**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    // Setup an event to allow our Form to handle this controls button click.
    // The Form containing this user control will need to attach a method to this event
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ButtonClick = null;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        
    // handle this control's button1 Click event
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**UserControl2**

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // map our InputTextBox property to TextBox on our control's UI
        InputTextBox = textBox1;
    }

    // add a TextBox property that can be accessed outside of the control
    public TextBox InputTextBox { get; }
}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        
    // setup method to handle the UserControl1's ButtonClick event
    private void userControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // call the TextBox property on UserControl2 and set its Text value.
        userControl2.InputTextBox.Text = "Test!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for you reply.
I tried that out, but it didnt work. it even doesnt run the "private void userControl11_ButtonClick" in the "Form1".
And I use a label and not a Textbox or must it always be a textbox?

Comment: I know it works, I tested it before I posted it. I had a couple of differences in my object names than you have, I've updated my names to match yours, this may be your problem. No, it doesn't have to be a TextBox, it can be any control. Just replace the TextBox with a Label.